# Kotlin zip each element with the one which is two indexes ahead

Tags: kotlin

I have a list with `(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5...)`. I'd like to zip `e1` with `e3`, `e2` with `e4` and so forth.

I could not find a zip method which lets you choose which element to zip with the current one.

```
items.map { item -> item.zipWithNext() } 
[e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8] -> [(e1, e3), (e2, e4), (e5, e7), (e6, e8)]
```

Comment: If you don't find one, you can implement your own with [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html). E.g. `fun List.zipWithNext(): List { // ... }`

Comment: Updating the tags, considering the title points it out correctly yo be Kotlin specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement the list's size must be a multiple of 4, like this:

```
val list = mutableListOf("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8")
```

So what you can do first is to swap the items in positions *1* and *2*, *5* and *6*, *9* and *10* and so on:

```
for (i in 0..list.size / 4 - 1) 
    list[4 * i + 1] = list[4 * i + 2].also { list[4 * i + 2] = list[4 * i + 1] }
```

Now the list is this:

```
[e1, e3, e2, e4, e5, e7, e6, e8]
```

Finally use `chunked(2)` to split the list in lists of 2 successive items:

```
val newList = list.chunked(2)
println(newList)
```

will print:

```
[[e1, e3], [e2, e4], [e5, e7], [e6, e8]]
```

If your initial list is not mutable or you want it unchanged, then create a new mutable list and operate on it:

```
val originalList = listOf("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8")
val list = originalList.toMutableList()
```

Answer (score 3):

`items.zipWithNext()` function is essentially an optimized version of `items.zip(items.drop(1))`.

Since you need to zip each item with an item that is *two* positions away, you can just use
`items.zip(items.drop(2))`:

```
    val items = listOf("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8")

    println(items.zip(items.drop(2)))
    // prints: [(e1, e3), (e2, e4), (e3, e5), (e4, e6), (e5, e7), (e6, e8)]
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @forpas It isn't? How so?

Comment: This is the expected result: `[(e1, e3), (e2, e4), (e5, e7), (e6, e8)]`

Comment: Ok, so be it. I hope this snippet could still be useful as an answer to the first part of the question: "I'd like to zip e1 with e3, e2 with e4 and so forth"

Comment: I'd just like to say that your snippet was in fact useful as well. It came in handy when dealing with another similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

you should do bunch of works.

```
val items = listOf("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8")

val partitionedItems = items.withIndex().partition { (index, _) -> index % 2 == 0 }

val oddList = partitionedItems.first.map { it.value }
val evenList = partitionedItems.second.map { it.value }
```

here we have odd and even lists like this:

> [e1, e3, e5, e7]
>
> [e2, e4, e6, e8]

next do a zipWithNext()

```
oddList.zipWithNext()
```

this creates data like this

> [(e1, e3), (e3, e5), (e5, e7)]

but we don't need this item :

> (e3, e5)

thus we should filter it.

```
val oddListPair = oddList.zipWithNext().withIndex().filter { (index, _) -> index % 2 == 0 }.map { it.value }
```

at last we have

> [(e1, e3), (e5, e7)]

in last step we should merge two odd and even lists.

```
oddListPair.zip(evenListPair){ a,b -> listOf(a,b)}.flatten()
```

full code is this.

```
val items = listOf("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8")
val partitionedItems = items.withIndex().partition { (index, _) -> index % 2 == 0 }

val oddList = partitionedItems.first.map { it.value } 
val evenList = partitionedItems.second.map { it.value }

val oddListPair = oddList.zipWithNext().withIndex().filter { (index, _) -> index % 2 == 0 }.map { it.value }
val evenListPair = evenList.zipWithNext().withIndex().filter { (index, _) -> index % 2 == 0 }.map { it.value }

oddListPair.zip(evenListPair){ a,b -> listOf(a,b)}.flatten()
```